# Select all data from a table which for the three ids that appear the most in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two Oracle SQL Tables:

```
Team and Work.
```

I want to select all the columns from the team table (this is fine) for three teams that appeart the most in the work table.

```
Team (teamId, name)
Work(workId, name, teamId).
```

I really don't know how to `select from count max`.

my first idea was to group the work table by the count of teamId but I can't group in a subquery...

Hope everything is clear, if not let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be something like this (not quite sure about syntax):

```
select * from team where teamid in (
   select teamid from (
      select teamid, count(workid)
      from work
      group by teamid
      order by 2)
   where rownum < 4);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It works except that you forgot to add DESC at the end of "order by 2 DESC". Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from team 
where teamID in(
    select top 3 teamId 
    from Work 
    group by teamId 
    order by COUNT(*) desc
    )
```

Comment: This query had a problem with the top 3, Oracle said that it was looking for a from...

Comment: `top` is not valid in Oracle. Not sure why this has been upvoted.

Comment: oh, its oracle, you have to use WHERE rownum <= 3 then